# ActiveRecord many_to_many association confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a quiz in Rails and I am drawing a blank on my associations.

I say I have three tables that I know are going to be there.

```
users
   |___id
   |___name

quizzes
   |___id
   |___user_id

questions
   |___id
   |___question
   |___poss_answer_one
   |___poss_answer_two
   |___poss_answer_three
   |___answer
   |___test_version
```

This is what I started with. The functionality of the site is as follows:

A user can select questions from up to three categories to add to their active quiz (quizzes). So a user will only have one quiz at a time because when they finish or restart a new one, the entry into the quizzes table will be re-created.

So the user has_one quiz and quizzes belongs_to users.

Next I am assuming that a quiz has_many questions and because questions are re-usable and can be included in many different quizzes, would it require a join table?

If so would it be

```
quiz_questions
   |___id
   |___question_id
   |___quiz_id
```

In that case it would require a has_many through.

Once I get this done I know how to model the associations, I am just confusing myself because of the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need a HABTM association (see this [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes))

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
end
```

Comment: It is my understanding that this is deprecated and should be done with a HMT association. I just want to make sure that my understanding of what belongs to what is correct. I understand the differences though, with a HABTM it is used if it is strictly a join table.

Comment: The HABTM in your case will use the quizzes_questions table by default. It does not seem that is deprecated. See [the API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info, looks like I was on the right path, just confused myself briefly.

Comment: Just take some migration example from the API docs and enjoy :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of valid approaches (I would argue). Following through with your `has_many through` suggestion the following could work. (Although a HATBM will certainly be simpler to implement and also valid for most use cases).

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :quizzes, through: :quiz_questions

class QuizQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :question

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :quiz_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :quiz_questions
```

---

You wrote:

> a user will only have one quiz at a time because when they finish or
>   restart a new one, the entry into the quizzes table will be
>   re-created.

I would say that even if this is the case you still require a `has_many` relationship. You are not 'recreating' the record in the quizzes table. You will be creating a new record. As a separate piece of functionality you may decide to delete to the(any) existing record in the quizzes table that belongs_to that particular user if these 'old' records are no longer required at all.

Answer (score 0):

A user can have zero, one or many quizzes(not just one), so the association should be an `has_many` association not just `has_one` association, for clarify

- a user has one quiz: `user.quiz`
- a user has many quizzes: `user.quizees`
- a quiz belongs to a user: `quiz.user`

Although a user can only have one quiz at a time, but after the user finished it, the user can have another new quiz.

- user1 -> quiz1
- user1 -> quiz2
- user1 -> quiz3

for a `many-to-many` association, you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many`(if you don't need extra columns in the table, except quiz_id and question_id) or introduce a join table